# Prevent Excel from automatically converting to date

Tags: format, microsoft-excel-2016

When I try to paste in certain values, Excel automatically converts it to a date.

There are solutions to this, the most common appearing to either paste as an image or to make sure the worksheet is formatted as `text` in advance.

The project I'm on requires a lot of copying and pasting (from various sources) to Excel and this issue keeps happening.

My question is, is there a way to prevent this behaviour (to turn it off completely) from within `Excel 2016` without manually making updates for each new document?

Answer (score 1):

You can format a workbook and save it as default (template), so any other workbook you start working on has those settings. You can do it by:

1. Open Excel to a blank workbook.
2. Format the blank file with all options desired (cell formatting is what you need).
3. Make sure to remove any values you entered in cells to test
   formatting unless you want them to appear in every blank workbook.
4. Once your changes are made, click on the File tab and choose Save
   As.
5. From the “Files of type” drop-down list, select “Excel Template
   (*.xltx)” and change the file name to “Book.”
6. Set the “Save in” location to the XLSTART folder. This folder is
   typically located in a path similar to C:Program Files/Microsoft
       Office/Office14/XLSTART. (Check out TechRepublic’s tip for quickly
       finding the XLSTART folder.)
7. Click Save.
8. Quit and re-open Excel. The blank workbook should contain the
   formatting you previously set.

Source: http://www.vitalyst.com/2011/03/productivity-101-setting-up-excel-default-formatting/